# Deadlock error when trying to sync goroutines

Tags: go, synchronization, goroutine

I'm facing an annoying problem. When I try to use `wg.Add()` to sync my routines, a deadlock error is raised.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func hello(ch chan int, num int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        i := <-ch
        if i == num {
            fmt.Println("Hello number:", i)
            ch <- (num - 1)
            defer wg.Done() // Same happens without defer
            return
        }
        ch <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go hello(ch, i, &wg)
    }

    ch <- 9

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

Outputs:

```
Start
Hello number: 9
Hello number: 8
Hello number: 7
Hello number: 6
Hello number: 5
Hello number: 4
Hello number: 3
Hello number: 2
Hello number: 1
Hello number: 0
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc04203a20c)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/sema.go:47 +0x3b
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc04203a200)
        C:/Go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:131 +0x81
main.main()
        C:/Users/Augusto Dias/Documents/GoLang/MT.go:34 +0x1a0

goroutine 18 [chan send]:
main.hello(0xc0420380c0, 0x0, 0xc04203a200)
        C:/Users/Augusto Dias/Documents/GoLang/MT.go:13 +0x197
created by main.main
        C:/Users/Augusto Dias/Documents/GoLang/MT.go:29 +0x151
exit status 2
```

When I use `wg.Add(9)` outside the for block, I got no error.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan int)

    wg.Add(9) // Use wg.Add(10) will raise deadlock too

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go hello(ch, i, &wg)
    }

    ch <- 9

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

Outputs:

```
Start
Hello number: 9
Hello number: 8
Hello number: 7
Hello number: 6
Hello number: 5
Hello number: 4
Hello number: 3
Hello number: 2
Hello number: 1
End
```

Why is this happening, I mean, why routines goes asleep when I wait for them all? Use the same channel for send and receive can be the source of this problem?

Comment: In the first one you're adding 10 to the WaitGroup, in the second you're adding 9. One goroutine isn't returning. (you should also defer at the start of the function, not under a conditional in a for loop.)

Comment: i got all the hellos in the first, what routine could be the non-returned?

Comment: You can probably guess it's number `0` since you haven't seen that printed, and the stack trace shows you it's blocked on the chan send on line 13.

Comment: @jimB I think its says 'zero' here main.hello(0xc0420380c0, 0x0, 0xc04203a200)

Comment: @BenjaminKadish: yup, that works in this case, though interpreting the actual arguments is often more complicated since they are values on the stack, so things like slices, strings, maps, will show the internal pointers, and the receiver and return values are included as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channel 0 (the call `go hello(ch, 0, &wg)`) since it is the last channel alive gets stuck on this line

```
ch <- (num - 1)
```

It is attempting to send to a channel but no one is there to receive it. Thus the function will wait indefinitely and never be done.

Some suggestions for how to remove this problem

- create a consumer in the main loop
- make the channel `ch` non blocking